# twitter bootstrap responsive span ordering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using twitter's bootstrap 2.3.2 to build a responsive site.

I am trying to arrange the spans correctly for when you stretch the window from tablet width (768px - 979px) to a laptop/desktop width (980px+)

In the two attached graphics, you can see what the tablet looks like and what it will look like when it is resized to a desktop width.

I know how to accomplish showing spans for only desktop .visible-desktop, but I am not sure how I would stack up the newsletter and check-in club on top of each in the 6th span/2nd row to the far right (in this case).

I've tried setting each span to span4, but it just doesn't display like it should in both views (tablet and desktop).

Any help is appreciated. I assume I might have to use some form of javascript to change spans once a certain width is reached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you have to split the Newsletter and Check In into separate rows? Just put them on the same row as the Blog post, stacked on top of each other. Am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: This is what UX guy came up with, and I am trying to get this to work in a responsive design. Do you think I should of had a voice during the wireframing process to tell the person that it might be too hard to accomplish what you see in the two images above?

Comment: No... what I'm saying is, put the 2 boxes (newsletter and check in) on the same Bootstrap row, but split the rows in your HTML. Maybe I'm not explaining it right. But like... `<div class="row"><div class="span6">Blog</div><div class="span6">Newsletter<br>Check in</div></div>`

Comment: @TimWasson I did that, but when I resize from desktop to tablet, it looks like http://cl.ly/Qb0S

Comment: Without seeing code I'm not sure how much help I'll be. Can you put it in a jsfiddle?